# I am trying to write a regular expression to validate nine numbers and only one capital letter at sixth position, such as:

Tags: javascript, html

```
13791A0512
```

The regular expression I used doesn't work for me:

```
/^[0-9]{9}[A-Z]{1}$/
```

Could you help me to figure out a working expression?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I told you your regex is looking for 9 digits followed by 1 letter, would that be enough of a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split the `{9}` to `{5}` and then the letter and then `{4}`

That is `^\d{5}[A-Z]\d{4}$`

- `^` -> should start with
- `\d{5}` -> 5 Digis
- `[A-Z]` -> a Capital Leter
- `\d{4}` -> 4 digits
- `$` -> End

```js
var re=/^\d{5}[A-Z]\d{4}$/;
console.log(re.test('13791A0512'));
```

Comment: `\w` doesn't enforce "one capital letter". The `i` flag should be removed, too.

Comment: `\w` matches digits and underscores too, so... Anyway, i believe the edited version is correct.

Comment: @nnnnnn you probably meant letters, not digits.  The `\w` matches any letter, underscore inclusive; whereas `\d` matches any digit. :)

Comment: @BekimBacaj - No, I meant digits. I said "too", as in, it matches digits and underscores in addition to letters.